# Sublime Text 2 + Tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, sublimetext

I've followed the instructions listed here: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/tortoise#Installation to install the Tortoise plugin.

1. Used package controll > install package > tortoise
2. Console seemed to install it correctly.

Problem: I am not receiving any additional options when right clicking files / folders.

I must be missing something??

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Sublime Text forums?

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble getting this to work too.

```
Open: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\TortoiseSVN
```

Check the path to the TortoiseProc.exe file is correct. That seems to connect it up to allow for commits and updates.

However, I don't see the package settings in the ST2 menu system still. Anyway, kind of works now.

Comment: I had a similar issue, the correct file was in C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\... though. Fixing the path to TortoiseProc.exe made Alt-U and Alt-C work, but no side bar yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but was able to fix it. I also eliminated the:
" error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified "
and " error: [WindowsError 2] The system cannot find the file specified "
dialog boxes from nagging between right clicks.

To get sublime_tortoise package(s) to work with the most recent version of TortoiseGit, I had to tweak the following file (assume you have the default installation paths):

C:\Users\%YOUR_USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Tortoise\Tortoise.py

Search for the following (Control + F), and change the following:

TortoiseProc.exe <- change to ->TortoiseGitProc.exe 
(Probably something like TortoiseSVNProc.exe for SVN)

also

tgit.exe <- change to -> tgittouch.exe
(Probably the same for all VCSs)

Also make sure the "C:\Program Files\" is the start of your paths if you are on 32-bit Windows and "C:\Program Files (x86)\" if you are on Windows 64-bit OS

Lastly, be sure to use double slashes where needed in both Tortiose.py and the User - Settings for Tortiose Package Control settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your comp? Tortoise requires a restart for the GUI to work.

Comment: Yep, no dice. And my key binding preferences are empty as well. Seems to not be installing correctly.

Comment: If you list installed packages from the package control it lists tortoise as installed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but it seems to be working after doing this:

1. Install package TortoiseSVN (thank you @divydovy for the hint) and restart Sublime
2. Install package Tortoise and close Sublime
3. Manually update some of the files from https://github.com/atwright147/sublime_tortoise using another editor (not sure if you could use Sublime and restart but I didn't)

This should get it up and running, however I'm not sure what will happen if there are any updates to this plugin, maybe watching that repo in step three would be a good idea.